# What does parameter a and b mean in an array of elements in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm practicing the sort function, the target is an array (ary) of a sentence. An example method I have seen is to build and use a block, and finally arrange the elements (words) in the array from short to long, and from a to z.

But I don't understand why there are two parameters a and b in this example, why should we find out a.length and b.length first? This is the original code:

```
ary = %w(
    Ruby is a open source programming language with a afocus on simplicity and productivity.
)

call_num = 0
sorted = ary.sort do |a, b|
    call_num += 1
    a.length <=> b.length
end

puts "Sort results: #{sorted}" #=>["a", "a", "on", "is", "and", "Ruby", "open", "with", "afocus", "source", "language", "simplicity", "programming", "productivity."]
puts "Number of array elements: #{ary.length}" #=> 14
puts "Number of calls to blocks: #{call_num}" #=>30
```

Comment: You read the documentation of `Enumerable#sort` at this link, right?  https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html  `a` and `b` are just arbitrary names we assign to the two arguments to the block. By the way, I prefer using `ary.sort_by { |a| a.length}` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @TPR : The block receives the arguments you want to compare. You use it for those cases where the default comparision does not do what you want.

Comment: _"why should we find out a.length and b.length first?"_ – well, if you want to sort them _by length_, you have to determine their `length` somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the following array of words by their length Ruby has to basically compare each word in the array to each other word (Note that this is not exactly how sorting works internally but in the context of this example we can assume that sorting works like this).

```
ary = %w(
  Ruby is a open source programming language with a afocus on simplicity and productivity.
)
```

That means in the first step Ruby will need to compare the words `Ruby` and `is` and has to decide how to sort those two words, then `is` and `a`, then `a` and `open`.

Those two words in each step of the comparison are the two block parameters `a` and `b`. `a.length <=> b.length` will then tell Ruby how to sort those two parameters (words).

See [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Comparable.html) and [`Enumerable#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort)